# Applying css to textbox for compulsory field

Tags: asp.net, css

1) [image]

2) [image]

I have a textbox which looks like 1st image. Instead of giving `'*'` mark for compulsory fields to be filled I want to depict the text box's right bottom corner marked with `RED` color. I am able to format as shown in image 1. I want the output something like the 2nd image where the red color is in right angle to the right-bottom. Following is my css that I am using. Please help how I can achieve format like 2nd image.

Css:

```
.txtbxcomp
{
    width: 120px;
    height: 25px;
    background-color: #F9F9F9;
    border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    text-transform:uppercase;

    font-family: Calibri;
    font-size: 14px;
    /*border-bottom-right-radius:1px;
    border-top-color:red;*/
    border-right-width:1px;
    border-right-color:red;
    border-bottom-width:1px;
    border-bottom-color:red;


}
```

And my text box is

```
<td class="r1" width="15%">PO No:
                                    </td>
                                    <td width="18%">
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="txt_Po_No" runat="server" Height="95%" CssClass="txtbxcomp" ></asp:TextBox>
                                        <%--<span style="color: Red;">*</span>--%>
                                    </td>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a solution for that, add an extra div along with the text-box and give style to that extra div. I am not sure about, is this a valid solution or not.

**CSS**

```
.txtbxcomp
{
    width: 120px;
    height: 25px;
    background-color: #F9F9F9;
    border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    text-transform:uppercase;

    font-family: Calibri;
    font-size: 14px;
    border-right-width:1px;
    border-right-color:red;
    border-bottom-width:1px;
    border-bottom-color:red;
 }

.border
{
    width: 100px;
    height: 1px;
    background:#CCCCCC;
    margin-top:-1px;
    z-index: 100;
    position: relative;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="tex" class="txtbxcomp">
    <div class="border"></div>
```

Find fiddle link [here](http://jsfiddle.net/d3XZG/1/)

Comment: Leo : Please see my edit. I have put my text box there, How do I go about this now. Do I have to put a div..?? and where..?? I added the div, but still not working.

Comment: I have a master page. I don't have html in my form.

Comment: My approach was assuming the elements are HTML elements

Comment: Done. It worked. I was adding the div above the text box. I added it below the text box. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind using ::after, try this way [DEMO Here](http://jsbin.com/AtiLOwA/1/edit?html,css,output):

HTML:

```
<div class="custom-border">
  <input type="text" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.custom-border
{
  display:inline-block;
  padding:none;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
}
.custom-border > input
{
    margin:0px;
    background-color: #F9F9F9;
    border:none;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-family: Calibri;
    font-size: 14px;
}

.custom-border:after{
    content:'';
    width:10%;
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    right:-1px;
    bottom:-1px;
    border: 1px solid;
    display:block;
    border-top-color: transparent;
    border-left-color: transparent;
    border-right-width:1px;
    border-right-color:red;
    border-bottom-width:1px;
    border-bottom-color:red;
}
```

If you need aspx markup, try:

```
<asp:Panel CssClass="custom-border" runat="server">
 <asp:TextBox ID="txt_Po_No" runat="server" Height="95%" CssClass="txtbxcomp" >  </asp:TextBox>
 </asp:Panel>
```